# Calling function that was declared virtual in interface (and implemented in derived class) inside base abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have the following inheritance model:

```
   interface      abstract class   concrete derived class
_________________________________________________________
IPriorityQueue -> APriorityQueue -> UnsortedPriorityQueue
```

My member function was declared purely virtual in the interface. In the abstract class, I want to use `size()` to already implement `empty()`, since if size = 0, then the priority queue is empty. `size()` is properly implemented in the derived class.

```cpp
#include <list>

template <typename K, typename V>
class   IPriorityQueue
{
    public:
        virtual int     size(void)  const = 0;
        virtual bool    empty(void) const = 0;
};

template <typename K, typename V>
class   APriorityQueue : virtual public IPriorityQueue<K, V>
{
    public:
        bool    empty(void) const { return (!size()); }
};

template <typename K, typename V>
class   UnsortedPriorityQueue : virtual public APriorityQueue<K, V>
{
    private:
        std::list<V>    _list;
    public:
        int             size(void)  const { return (this->_list.size()); }
};

int main()
{
    UnsortedPriorityQueue<int, char>    test;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
../../libft/APriorityQueue.hpp:49:37: error: there are no arguments to 'size' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'size' must be available [-fpermissive]
   bool empty(void) const { return (!size()); }
                                     ^~~~
../../libft/APriorityQueue.hpp:49:37: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

I read in some other answers on StackOverflow that one has to specify the namespace, so I modified  it the following way:

```cpp
        bool    empty(void) const { return (!IPriorityQueue<K, V>::size()); }
```

But now I get a linker error complaining that `IPriorityQueue<K, V>::size()` is not implemented:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK14APriorityQueueIiNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE5emptyEv[_ZNK14APriorityQueueIiNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE5emptyEv]+0x28): undefined reference to `IPriorityQueue<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::size() const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there any way I can figure this out? Is such a design even possible? Thank you in advance

Comment: please post a [mcve], ie some code that does not require to stitch pieces together to reprodce the error

Comment: I updated the question with a short program, sorry

Comment: It's not necessary to template the interface and the abstract class. Remove the template parameters for those and it will compile. You also don't require virtual inheritance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
bool    empty(void) const { return (!size()); }
```

with

```
bool    empty(void) const { return (!this->size()); }//note i have added this->
```

and that will solve your problem.

Here's the rule

> the compiler does not look in dependent base classes when looking up nondependent names .

[Here's](https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html) a good article for reading more about this.